# CSS/JS Randomly Position Elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to do something fancy by randomly placing several `<p>` elements in a div. I am aware of the `Math.random()` js function, but since I'm placing them randomly with absolute position I get some overlapping :\

So, my question is: is there a simple way to achieve this?

[image: Badly drawn example]

**Edit**:
After analyzing the possible duplicate, I found out the solution used does not fit my needs.. They basically create a grid since they know exactly what each element will contain.. My `<p>` elements will have text inside that can go from 9 chars to a larger number of chars...

Comment: TylerH and SW4 can you review my question? I have edited it..

Comment: did you look at the second answer in the linked question?

Comment: @TylerH, I did now :P thanks.. It seems I am creating a big problem and I don't need big problems xD So I'll just "fake" the random position with CSS.. If it turns out good enough, I can post it here as an answer.
Thanks :)